# How to connect apache-doris instance to postgres with ssh tunnel

Tags: java, postgresql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I dont know how to connect postgres db to apache doris instance with ssh tunnel integration.

Hi, im trying to connect apache doris to postgres with catalogs.
Im using this documentation https://doris.apache.org/docs/dev/lakehouse/multi-catalog/jdbc, and work with normal database connection, but i dont know how to do that with ssh tunnel.
First i think to use another driver with ssh included like https://github.com/cactuslab/jdbc-sshj/tree/master, but i dont found documentation to use custom drivers in apache.

Do you know some solution? If it is the case, please share me

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else encounters a similar issue, this has been solved on the [Apache Doris Github repository](https://github.com/apache/doris/discussions/22478). The main idea is, Apache Doris only supports catalog for this for the time being.